# How to make an array with CNotLike

Tags: powershell

```
$intel = "AppUp.IntelGraphicsControlPanel"
$nvidia = "NVIDIACorp.NVIDIAControlPanel"
$store = "*Store*"
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -CNotLike $intel -and $_.DisplayName -CNotLike $nvidia -and $_.DisplayName -CNotLike $store} | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Is it possible to use an array due to too long string with variables? Something like (may be)

```
$apps = @()
Foreach ($app in $apps)
{    }
```

Comment: what does `cnotlike` [case-sensitive not like] have to do with "too long string"? i am very confused ... [*grin*]

Comment: I mean it's hard to read. cnotlike doesn't take these 3 vars and delete all others provisioned packages.

Comment: Please _edit the question_ and add an example of sample input, what you do get and what you'd like to get.

Comment: @farag - ah! your test seems to be the center of the problem. you use `-and` when i suspect you really want `-or`. the way that "Theo" used the regex OR symbol `|` seems the better way to do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can shorten this repeating `-cnotlike` using a regular expression `-cnotmath` like this:

```
$re = "AppUp\.IntelGraphicsControlPanel|NVIDIACorp\.NVIDIAControlPanel|.*Store.*"
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online | 
    Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -cnotmatch $re} | 
        Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Regex Details:

```
                                 Match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
   AppUp                         Match the character string “AppUp” literally (case sensitive)
   \.                            Match the character “.” literally
   IntelGraphicsControlPanel     Match the character string “IntelGraphicsControlPanel” literally (case sensitive)
|
                                 Or match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
   NVIDIACorp                    Match the character string “NVIDIACorp” literally (case sensitive)
   \.                            Match the character “.” literally
   NVIDIAControlPanel            Match the character string “NVIDIAControlPanel” literally (case sensitive)
|
                                 Or match this alternative (the entire match attempt fails if this one fails to match)
   .                             Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed)
      *                          Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   Store                         Match the character string “Store” literally (case sensitive)
   .                             Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed)
      *                          Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$apps = @(  
"AppUp.IntelGraphicsControlPanel",  
"Microsoft.LanguageExperiencePackru-RU",  
"Microsoft.Windows.Photos",  
"Microsoft.ScreenSketch",  
"NVIDIACorp.NVIDIAControlPanel",  
"Store")  
(Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Where-Object {$_.Name -notmatch ($apps -join '|')}).name
```